# Finding the direction of an induced current, swinging pendulum

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

[image: conductor in magnetic field]

The conductor shown in #1 is held still in position #2. The switch s1 is now open, and the switch s2 is now closed, see #1. There is no current going through the conductor as its held still. Then, the conductor is released and an electric current is induced. Find the direction of this current:

1 As the conductor swings towards the lowest point.

2 As the conductor makes its way up to the right after having passed the lowest point.

Since the flux is reduced when the conductor makes its way down the lowest point (angle between area vector and b field goes towards 90 degrees), the flux is reduced. Therefore i think there must be induced a magnetic field going in the same direction as the field in #2, and the force on the conductor must be opposite of the direction of the velocity (Lenz's law) i.e to the left, and therefore the current should be going into the plane of the paper. Because the flux is reduced after the conductor has passed the lowest point and swings up to the right, my idea is that it should be the excact opposite (current going out of the plane of the paper). However this is not correct apparently.

It's a bit of a complex problem, so if you need additonal details or explanations please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . . . and the force on the conductor must be opposite of the direction
>   of the velocity (Lenz's law) i.e to the left, and therefore the
>   current should be going into the plane of the paper.

**Q** So when the conductor has passed the vertical which way is the conductor moving and so which way should the opposition to motion be?
**A** The same as before, to the left, and so the induced current must be in the same direction as before.

Before the conductor reached the vertical position the induced current produce a clockwise magnetic field around the bottom conductor thus trying to increase the (downward) magnetic flux through the loop to try and counteract the decreasing magnetic flux due to the external magnetic field..

On the other side of the vertical the direction of the induced current and hence the induced magnetic field is the same but note that now that induced magnetic field and hence the flux is upwards through the loop and it is trying to reduce the increase in magnetic flux through the loop due to the external magnetic field.

**Update** as a result of a comment

The external magnetic field always points downwards.

[image]

The magnetic field due to the induced current has a downward component through the loop when the loop is left of vertical (left picture) and an upward component through the loop when the loop is right of vertical (right picture).

Comment: How do you know if the magnetic flux through the loop goes downwards or upward? How does producing a clockwise magnetic field around the bottom conductor increase the magnetic flux through the loop? Why does flux change from going downwards through the loop to upwards through the  loop? If there was produced a magnetic field going in the opposite direction of the original B field you could still get a force going to the left (and a current going up of the plane of the paper). How does a clockwise magnetic field give a magnetic force on the conductor going to the left?

Comment: @Pame I have added a diagram to my answer.

Comment: How does the magnetic field going downwards through the loop decrease increase the flux, and how does the magnetic field going upwards through the loop decrease the flux? Furthermore, i still don't see how a magnetic field going clockwise like that produces a force acting to the left on the loop.

Comment: There is an external magnetic  field (green) which the induced magnetic field (red) tries to increase on the left and decrease on the right. The force must be the same on both sides as the induced current (into the screen) and the external magnetic field are in the same direction both on the left and the right. The induced current is trying to "stop" the conductor moving - Lenz.

Comment: how do you know the induced magnetic field is in the same plane as the conductor ( and not above it so the field lines don't hit the conductor or something). How do you find the induced force apart from using Lenz' law?